# Executor service only executing the first task

Tags: java, linux, jsp

I have written a program to execute two commands that run in the foreground in the shell until ^c is pressed on the terminal.

shell command

```
./weed master -mdir=/var/lib/qualebs/weed
```

the output for above command is

```
qualebs@qualebs-HP-655-Notebook-PC:~$ cd weed_0.64_linux_386/
qualebs@qualebs-HP-655-Notebook-PC:~/weed_0.64_linux_386$ ./weed master -mdir=/var/lib/qualebs/weed -port=9333
I0518 00:40:16 24540 file_util.go:19] Folder /var/lib/qualebs/weed Permission: -rwxr-xr-x
I0518 00:40:16 24540 topology.go:84] Using default configurations.
I0518 00:40:16 24540 master_server.go:56] Volume Size Limit is 30000 MB
I0518 00:40:16 24540 master.go:66] Start Seaweed Master 0.64 at :9333
I0518 00:40:16 24540 raft_server.go:97] Recovered from log
I0518 00:40:22 24540 master_server.go:82] [ localhost:9333 ] localhost:9333 becomes leader.
```

then I start the volume server with command and output as follows respectively

```
qualebs@qualebs-HP-655-Notebook-PC:~$ cd weed_0.64_linux_386/
qualebs@qualebs-HP-655-Notebook-PC:~/weed_0.64_linux_386$ ./weed volume -dir=/var/lib/qualebs/weed -port=9444
I0518 00:42:18 24583 file_util.go:19] Folder /var/lib/qualebs/weed Permission: -rwxr-xr-x
I0518 00:42:18 24583 volume.go:103] loading file /var/lib/qualebs/weed/1.idx readonly false
I0518 00:42:18 24583 store.go:212] data file /var/lib/qualebs/weed/1.dat, replicaPlacement=000 v=2 size=2021448 ttl=
I0518 00:42:18 24583 volume.go:103] loading file /var/lib/qualebs/weed/2.idx readonly false
I0518 00:42:18 24583 store.go:212] data file /var/lib/qualebs/weed/2.dat, replicaPlacement=000 v=2 size=728808 ttl=
I0518 00:42:18 24583 volume.go:103] loading file /var/lib/qualebs/weed/3.idx readonly false
I0518 00:42:18 24583 store.go:212] data file /var/lib/qualebs/weed/3.dat, replicaPlacement=000 v=2 size=1215160 ttl=
I0518 00:42:18 24583 volume.go:103] loading file /var/lib/qualebs/weed/4.idx readonly false
I0518 00:42:18 24583 store.go:212] data file /var/lib/qualebs/weed/4.dat, replicaPlacement=000 v=2 size=1272992 ttl=
I0518 00:42:18 24583 volume.go:103] loading file /var/lib/qualebs/weed/5.idx readonly false
I0518 00:42:18 24583 store.go:212] data file /var/lib/qualebs/weed/5.dat, replicaPlacement=000 v=2 size=404944 ttl=
I0518 00:42:18 24583 volume.go:103] loading file /var/lib/qualebs/weed/6.idx readonly false
I0518 00:42:18 24583 store.go:212] data file /var/lib/qualebs/weed/6.dat, replicaPlacement=000 v=2 size=834640 ttl=
I0518 00:42:18 24583 volume.go:103] loading file /var/lib/qualebs/weed/7.idx readonly false
I0518 00:42:18 24583 store.go:212] data file /var/lib/qualebs/weed/7.dat, replicaPlacement=000 v=2 size=588240 ttl=
I0518 00:42:18 24583 store.go:219] Store started on dir: /var/lib/qualebs/weed with 7 volumes max 7
I0518 00:42:18 24583 volume.go:90] Start Seaweed volume server 0.64 at 0.0.0.0:9444
```

Java code to automatically start the master and volume server

```
public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        final ServletContext servletContext = sce.getServletContext();
        executor.execute(new WeedMaster());
        executor.execute(new WeedVolume());
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        executor.shutdown();
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ContextListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private class WeedMaster implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                List<String> command = new ArrayList<>();
                command.add("./weed");
                command.add("master");
                command.add("-mdir=/var/lib/qualebs/weed");
                command.add("port=9333");
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
                pb.directory(new File("/home/qualebs/weed_0.64_linux_386/"));
                Process start = pb.start();
                start.waitFor();
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ContextListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

    }

    private class WeedVolume implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                List<String> command = new ArrayList<>();
                command.add("./weed");
                command.add("volume");
                command.add("-dir=/var/lib/qualebs/weed");
                command.add("port=9444");
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
                pb.directory(new File("/home/qualebs/weed_0.64_linux_386/"));
                Process start = pb.start();
                start.waitFor();
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ContextListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Then I deploy my application to the server only to find that the first command is executed and the master server is running but no volume server. why isn't the second task executed?

when both commands are executed from terminal I can see both master and volume are running

```
qualebs@qualebs-HP-655-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo ps auwx | grep weed
[sudo] password for qualebs: 
qualebs  24540  0.0  0.1 798100  7008 pts/1    Sl+  00:40   0:00 ./weed master -mdir=/var/lib/qualebs/weed -port=9333
qualebs  24583  0.0  0.1 798100  9124 pts/6    Sl+  00:42   0:00 ./weed volume -dir=/var/lib/qualebs/weed -port=9444
qualebs  24749  0.0  0.0  22516  1020 pts/18   S+   00:48   0:00 grep --color=auto weed
```

but when run from process builder I have only master listening on port 9333

Comment: Add logging after each `start.waitFor()` to see if both task were ran at all and if one of them didnt terminate for some reason

Comment: I have seen the mistake in my `command.add("port=9333");` I forgot `-` before port. changed to `command.add("-port=9333");` and everything worked fine. I am so sorry folks for the false alarm.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use:

```
    executor.execute(new WeedMaster());
    executor.execute(new WeedVolume());
```

you should use insteed:

```
    executor.submit(new WeedMaster());
    executor.submit(new WeedVolume());
```

According to the docs `executor.execute(Runnable)` can invoke runnable on current (calling) thread in the discretion of implementation. Quote:

> void execute(Runnable command)
>
> Executes the given command at some time in the future. The command may
>   execute in a new thread, in a pooled thread, or in the calling thread,
>   at the discretion of the Executor implementation.